# MySQL: testing multiple values across rows

Tags: mysql

I've been given a MySQL database of college graduates and a table called 'Subjects' includes: StudentID, SubjectName, Exams.

The Exams column is for the exams taken within each course. They have names like Part I, Part II, Sect A, Sect B etc. Degree courses have different exam names to other courses, so names starting with 'Part' apply to degrees only, and Sect A might apply to a vocational Accountancy course.

A simplified version of the table looks like this:

```
StudentID   Subject     Exam
--------------------------------------
1234        Mathematics Part I
5678        Music       Sect A
9101        Geography   Part I
1234        Accountancy Sect A
```

Notice that sometimes people switch to and from degree courses, like 1234 above. I've been asked to write a query to find all the people who haven't taken any degree-related exams. So 1234 shouldn't be returned in the results because they've done a degree-related exam (Mathematics Part I) as well as a non-degree exam (Accountancy Sect A).

This query takes me some way there but misses people like 1234 who've done both types of exam:

```
SELECT `StudentID` FROM `Subjects` WHERE `Exam` NOT IN ('Part I', 'Part II', etc)
```

I can't work out how to refine the query. I tried this but it crashes phpMyAdmin so I guess it's wrong!

```
SELECT `StudentID` FROM `Subjects` 
WHERE `Exam` NOT IN ('Part I', 'Part II') 
AND `StudentID` NOT IN(SELECT `StudentID` FROM `Subjects` WHERE `Exam` LIKE 'Pt I%')
```

Comment: I think it would be simpler if there was another table which identified exactly which course belonged to which award.

Comment: That's an idea. Apparently the database was made 8 years ago, with no thought as to how it would be queried.

Comment: Well, you're in charge now! There should be a table of students, a table of subjects and a table that tells us which student took which subject (and when!)

Comment: Iserni's query below works fine but I'd imagine the separate tables as you suggest might make for a faster query. I'll see how fast the query below is, and make separate tables if necessary. It's a read-only database which is part of a completed research project, and I'll have to pass any changes by the academics I'm working with first (sadly I'm not completely in charge!).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query takes me some way there but misses people like 1234 who've done both types of exam:
>
> SELECT `StudentID` FROM `Subjects` WHERE `Exam` NOT IN ('Part I', 'Part II', etc)

As you noticed, this query will return multiple-exam students multiple times. It will just filter out those *subjects* you don't want. The tuple where student 1234 takes Sect A will remain.

To solve the problem you need to think the other way: the students you want are *those that aren't those that you don't want*

So first you get all the students you *don't* want, once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `StudentID` 
    FROM `Subjects` 
    WHERE `Exam` IN ('Part I', 'Part II', etc)
```

Now you want to query the list of students that are *not* in this list. You do this by `LEFT JOIN`ing the list of all subjects (where Students are present multiple times) with the list of *unwanted* students. Whenever a name in the full list can be matched with an unwanted student, the unwanted.* columns will be populated accordingly. If this can't be done (i.e. the subject does not belong to an unwanted student), those columns will be NULL.

So you just select those tuples where `unwanted.StudentId IS NULL`. Those will have the first table's columns populated. Of these you only require StudentID. And since the StudentID may appear multiple times, you add a `DISTINCT` clause on the outer `SELECT` too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wanted.StudentID FROM `Subjects` AS wanted
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT `StudentID` 
             FROM `Subjects` 
             WHERE `Exam`  IN ('Part I', 'Part II', etc)
    ) AS unwanted
    ON (wanted.StudentId = unwanted.StudentId)
    WHERE unwanted.StudentId IS NULL;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cef2/1) you can see a SQL Fiddle; it returns as expected student 5678.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. I was fiddling with self joins last night before I went to bed (I'm in the UK) but just couldn't work out the right one! Thanks for the explanation, too.